# App lock-up on Windows 8 (apparently disk related)

Tags: windows-8, ssd

Since installing Windows 8 (the problem didn't happen on Windows 7), my laptop will lock up:

- All apps will gradually stop responding when interacted with, for a minute or so, and then everything starts working again.

The problem normally happens soon after I log in.

Looking at Task Manager I see this during the lock-up:

[image: task manager during app lockup]

Active time == 100%.
Disk Transfer rate == 0.

The disk is an [SSD Crucial M4 CT256M4SSD2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148443)

**Hardware Ids info from Device Manager:**

```
IDE\DiskM4-CT256M4SSD2__________________________0001____
IDE\M4-CT256M4SSD2__________________________0001____
IDE\DiskM4-CT256M4SSD2__________________________
M4-CT256M4SSD2__________________________0001____
GenDisk
```

**Output from [DiskCheckup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm):**

*** DiskCheckup V3.1 Build: 1006 Report ***

```
SysInfo DLL Version:            SysInfo v1.0 Build: 1030
Time of export:                 13:19:07 19-Apr-2013

Device information:             
   Device ID:                   0
   Interface:                   RAID
   Device Capacity:             244191 MB
   Serial Number:               0000000011180306C84D
   Model Number:                M4-CT256M4SSD2
   Firmware Revision:           0001
   Partitions:                  
      C:         244195 MB

ATA information:                

   Disk geometry:               
      Cylinders:                31130
      Tracks/Cylinder:          255
      Sectors/Track:            63
      Bytes/Sector:             512
      Total disk sectors:       500118192
      Logical sector size:      512
      Physical sector size:     512
      Media rotation rate:      SSD
      Buffer size:              0 KB
      ECC size:                 0 Bytes

   Standards compliance:          
      ATA8-ACS Supported:         Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-7 Supported:      Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-6 Supported:      Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-5 Supported:      Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-4 Supported:      Yes
      Serial/Parallel:            Serial
         SATA 3.0 Compilance:     Yes
         SATA 2.6 Compilance:     Yes
         SATA 2.5 Compilance:     Yes
         SATA II: Ext Compilance: Yes
         SATA 1.0a Compilance:    Yes
         ATA8-AST Compilance:     Yes
   World Wide ID:                 500A07510306C84D

   Feature support:                                          
      SMART supported:                                       Yes
         SMART enabled:                                      Yes
      SMART self-test supported:                             Yes
      SMART error log supported:                             Yes
      LBA supported:                                         Yes
      IORDY supported:                                       Yes
      CFast supported:                                       No
      DMA supported:                                         Yes
         Maximum Multiword DMA mode supported:               2
         Multiword DMA selected:                             None
         Maximum UltraDMA mode supported:                    5
         UltraDMA selected:                                  5
      Maximum PIO mode supported:                            4
      SATA Compliance:                                       Yes
         NCQ priority information supported:                 Yes
         Unload while NCQ commands are outstanding supported:No
         Phy Event Counters supported:                       Yes
         Receipt of power management requests supported:     Yes
         NCQ feature set supported:                          Yes
         SATA Gen2 Signaling Speed (3.0Gb/s) supported:      Yes
         SATA Gen1 Signaling Speed (1.5Gb/s) supported:      Yes
         Software Settings Preservation:                     Supported, Enabled
         In-order data delivery:                             Not supported
         Initiating power management:                        Supported, Enabled
         DMA Setup auto-activation:                          Supported, Enabled
         Non-zero buffer offsets:                            Not supported
      Trusted Computing supported:                           No
      Host Protected Area (HPA) supported:                   Yes
      Read look-ahead supported:                             Yes
         Read look-ahead enabled:                            Yes
      Write cache supported:                                 Yes
         Write cache enabled:                                Yes
      Power management supported:                            Yes
      Security mode supported:                               Yes
         Security mode enabled:                              No
      Device Configuration Overlay (DCO) supported:          Yes
      48bit Addressing supported:                            Yes
      Auto Acoustic Managment (AAM) supported:               No
      Power-up in Standby (PUIS) supported:                  No
      Advanced Power Management (APM) supported:             Yes
         Advanced Power Management (APM) enabled:            Yes
         Current APM level:                                  Maximum performance
      CompactFlash Association (CFA) supported:              No
      General Purpose Logging (GPL) supported:               Yes
      Streaming supported:                                   No
      Media card pass through supported:                     No
      Extended power conditions supported:                   No
      Extended status reporting supported:                   No
      Write-read-verify supported:                           Yes
         Write-read-verify enabled:                          No
      Free-fall control supported:                           No
      TRIM command supported:                                Yes
      SCT command transport supported:                       Yes
      NV Cache enabled:                                      No
      NV Cache Power Management supported:                   No

SMART ATTRIBUTES:
 ID Description                   Status Value Worst Threshold Raw Value     TEC
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Raw Read Error Rate           OK     100   100   50        90            N.A.  
  5 Reallocated Sector Count      OK     100   100   10        0             N.A.  
  9 Power On Time                 OK     100   100   1         5002          N.A.  
 12 Power Cycle Count             OK     100   100   1         645           N.A.  
170 (Unknown attribute)           OK     100   100   10        0             N.A.  
171 (Unknown attribute)           OK     100   100   1         32            N.A.  
172 (Unknown attribute)           OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
173 (Unknown attribute)           OK     94    94    10        199           N.A.  
174 (Unknown attribute)           OK     100   100   1         5             N.A.  
181 (Unknown attribute)           OK     100   100   1         8327986808032 N.A.  
183 SATA Downshift Error Count    OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
184 End-to-End error              OK     100   100   50        0             N.A.  
187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors OK     100   100   1         505           N.A.  
188 Command Timeout               OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
189 High Fly Writes               OK     100   100   1         124           N.A.  
195 Hardware ECC Recovered        OK     100   100   1         124415        N.A.  
196 Reallocation Event Count      OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
197 Current Pending Sector Count  OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
198 Uncorrectable Sector Count    OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
199 UltraDMA CRC Error Count      OK     100   100   1         0             N.A.  
202 Data Address Mark Errors      OK     94    94    1         6             N.A.  
206 Flying Height                 OK     100   100   1         32            N.A.
```

Comment: Post the S.M.A.R.T data for the drive.

Comment: I just saw another question that recommended updating the firmware on the SSD (for a different sounding problem). I will try that.

Comment: Hmm. Assuming I have a Crucial M4 2.5" SSD, the Windows 8 updater doesn't work (it doesn't list any drives). (from here: http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx)

Comment: It might be good if you verify what hardware you have exactly. We don't know what hardware you have.  Have you tried the manual boot method?  The instructions show how you can verify the drives `Hardware ids` information.

Comment: OK, I've successfully updated the BIOS to the latest version using the bootable ISO instead of the utility. Fingers crossed this fixes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

> **IDE**\DiskM4

sound like you run the HDD in the slow old IDE mode. Use AHCI instead. Install the latest AHCI drivers, go to the BIOS/UEFI and change the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI.

Comment: Oh, thanks for this advice - I'll give this a try.